# Numpy vectorised or numba jit decrementation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

I have a numpy array of integers which I want to decrement by a certain number n. This array represents the frequency of some event occurrence. A small sample looks something like this

[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 12, 24, 0, 23]

I want to subtract a number n from the array with two conditions.

1. The total array sum should decrease by n.
2. No element in the array should be less than 0
3. It should be done in such a way that the subtraction is evenly carried out across the array elements.

For instance, if we have an array [0, 1, 1, 12, 2] and n=2, the resultant array should be [0, 1, 1, 10, 2]. This is because if we want to carry the subtraction out evenly among the elements, and n=2 and the array sum is 16, the way to evenly spread the subtraction is to subtract 1 every 4th value. In this case, the 12 is both the 4th and 8th value, so it is decremented twice.

Intuition if the above is still confusing: say each number in the array represents the number of dogs in various kennels, and I know overall 20 dogs disappeared. I could randomly pick out 20 dogs with np.random.choice, but this is too slow for a very large array so I need to simulate that by equally distributing/spacing the disappearances across all the dogs in the array.

I have been struggling to implement this in a vectorised way, since i have a very large array I need to operate on many times. Solutions with numba's jit would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok for the vectorized solution. *What did you tried*, for example, with plain loops? Jitting the loop-based code should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I don't understand how exactly you define the 'evenly carried out subtraction'.

Comment: So I haven't managed to implement it as intended with plain loops, but I tried to formalise the process as much as possible as described above. @orlp, when I say that I mean imagine we rolled the array out as follows: [0, 2, 4] would become [0,2,2,4,4,4,4]. In this array, n=3  would mean indexes 1, 3, 5 are subtracted since they're evenly spaced. Returning to the original array, this would mean [0, 1, 2] would be the result, because we decrement the 2 once, and the 4 twice with those indices.